# recognizing python packages installed on your ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pip

I want to do an automation to recognize Python packages installed in Ubuntu.

For example in the code below,
the program, when executed, must recognize that the `pandas` library exists in the system. If it exists, writes `exists`. If not, writes `does not exist`.

```bash
SR=$(pip show pandas) 

if [ '$SR' ];
then
    if [ $(echo $?) -eq 1 ];
    then
        echo "não existe"
    else    
        echo "existe"    
    fi
fi
```

but I'm not getting this return

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work you first need to echo the command so
`SR=$(pip show pandas)` needs to be changed to `SR=$(echo "pip show pandas")`. You also need to run it, so before the second if statment you need to add `$SR`.

The code should look as follows:

```
SR=$(echo "pip show pandas") 

if [ '$SR' ];
then
    $SR
    if [ $(echo $?) -eq 1 ];
    then
        echo "não existe"
    else    
        echo "existe"    
    fi
fi
```

P.S.
I am assuming that in the first if statement you wanna check if the `SR` exists the code you have would not work for this. You need to change it to `if [ -n "${SR+1}" ]`

The updated should be like this:

```
SR=$(echo "pip show pandas") 

if [ -n "${SR+1}" ];
then
    $SR
    if [ $(echo $?) -eq 1 ];
    then
        echo "não existe"
    else    
        echo "existe"    
    fi
fi
```